# How to track down bad performance on an api-server

Tags: performance, performance-tuning

If my api-server shows bad performance, such as high cpu - can this be blamed on the service or on the server?

If a regular app-server shows bad performance, all I can do is track down the methods and the lines of code consuming the resources and tune them. But how does it work with an api-server? Can code be the problem for bad performance on an api-server? If so, how?

All we do in our code is to call our api, which means that bad performance on an api/restapi server can never be blamed on the code, is this right or wrong?

I know that the question is vague, but this is something I am struggling to understand.

Thank you.

Comment: There should be at least some caching on the api-server side so that even if the same client requests a big listing every 2 seconds the response should be faster than without caching.

Comment: @ychaouche Is our production code within the API-server?

Comment: In my understanding of the terminology production simply means the running code that you are actually using for real (on production), in contrast to testing code or alpha/beta code. Thus, the api-server has production code and the application that uses that api-server also has production code.

Comment: Ok. So for example, if I make an streaming app that uses some kind of third party streaming service/api, and host it on a server, or a location app which uses google maps api. This server is then an api-server?

Comment: It is possible to write bad application code that calls the wrong functions / web services in the api-server or calls them very frequently instead of caching the results on its side. This is particularly true for api calls inside of a loop where the result of the call is always the same. This is just an example and in that case the call should be made outside of the loop.

Comment: No. The api-server in your case is google maps or the third party's server. Your code is simply the client code, or the application code.

Comment: @ychaouche Ok, I understand. So if one of my api-servers shows high cpu or low memory, the problem is not in my production code, but in my server or the api itself?

Comment: Not necessarily. It is also possible that the implementation of the API is time-consuming. You can not be 100% positive it comes from the app or from the server. One solution to troubleshoot this is to log every api-call in a log file and see how many calls you have. If you have many calls from the same client than you need to investigate why that client is making so many calls and is that really necessary. If you have a very small amount of calls then you should investigate why the server is taking too long to respond.

Comment: Please update your question with specific details about the problem.   This is too general to be asked here.  What technology are you using?  How are you testing?   What have you tried to correct the problem?